# Syntax error in the SQL expression - without syntax error

Tags: mysql, spring, mariadb, liquibase

I follow a guide, I have downloaded their code and, as is usually the case with github projects, nothing works.
There are two such commands:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_access_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token LONG VARBINARY,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(255),
  client_id VARCHAR(255),
  authentication LONG VARBINARY,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE oauth_refresh_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token LONG VARBINARY,
  authentication LONG VARBINARY
);
```

When I start the project, I receive the following info:

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in the SQL
>   expression

```
"CREATE TABLE OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN (
  TOKEN_ID VARCHAR(255),
  TOKEN LONG VARBINARY[*],
  AUTHENTICATION_ID VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  USER_NAME VARCHAR(255),
  CLIENT_ID VARCHAR(255),
  AUTHENTICATION LONG VARBINARY,
  REFRESH_TOKEN VARCHAR(255)
) ";
```

expected:

```
"RAW, (, FOR, UNSIGNED, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"
```

What can be wrong ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Which guide are you following?

Comment: https://kobietydokodu.pl/projekt-bilet-2-konfiguracja-bazy-danych/ @OrtomalaLokni

Comment: I am not 100% sure, so I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer. The column declarations for token and authentication look strange to me - they seem to have two datatypes (`LONG` and `VARBINARY`) rather than just one. Based completely on a guess of the actual datatypes, I would remove the `LONG` from each one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

> LONG VARBINARY

to:

> LONGVARBINARY

on the TOKEN and the AUTHENTICATION fields